# How to hightlight an element with a circle

Tags: javascript, jquery, overlay, highlight

I have an element `$('.li .menu).first()`. I have opened a modal with overlay. I want to highlight only this element with a circle. How do I do that.

**Note:** There is overlay below because of modal.

Comment: You can create a circle in css with the border radius property. Then just place it where the element you want highlighted is.

Comment: this should be done dynamically in js

Answer (score 1):

Using an SVG with no fill.

```
<svg>
   <circle cx="100" cy="50" r="40" stroke="red" stroke-width="2" fill="none"/>
</svg>
```